# Image is not pushed in docker private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Docker version 17.03.0-ce on client machine. I am using registry version 2. The machine runs on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

Steps:

1. I created an image
2. I created another tag for it of the form `<hostname>:5000/<username>/<repository>:<tag>`
3. I executed the command `docker push <hostname>:5000/<username>/<repository>:<tag>`

Three mentions:

1. **The private repository uses http, not https, as it is mentioned in the error message.**
2. I created a file "docker.json" in the path
       "/etc/docker", and added the following line: `{"insecure-registries": ["<hostname>:5000"] }` and executed "sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"
3. `curl http://<hostname>:5000/v2/_catalog` works fine from client
   machine.

After all these steps, I get the following message:

```
Get https://<hostname>:5000/v2: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Comment: Can you try this - docker push <docker hub user name>:<repository name>:<tag> Try tagging in the same format only and then upload

Comment: I get the same message.

Comment: I also added the host name and port in front of that, because if I only use the format "<docker hub user name>:<repository name>:<tag>", it would try to push to docker hub. I want to push the image to a local private repository which I created on another machine.

Comment: Can you post the output from `docker info -f '{{json .RegistryConfig.IndexConfigs}}'`

Comment: {"docker.io":{"Name":"docker.io","Mirrors":null,"Secure":true,"Official":true}}

Comment: Also post your daemon.json file along with `journalctl -u docker | grep daemon.json`

Comment: `journalctl -u docker | grep daemon.json` doesn't have an output. I also ran `locate daemon.json`, can't seem to find it.

Comment: And verify that `$DOCKER_HOST` is not defined in your shell.

Comment: It is not. I ran `echo $DOCKER_HOST`, doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created a file "docker.json" in the path "/etc/docker"

That's not the correct filename, you need to create a file named `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Then rerun the steps you've performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding plain http support using the docker daemon.json file.

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Contents

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["registry:5000"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding insecure registry setting in /etc/default/docker file in docker_opts variable

```
DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry registry_ip:5000
```

Comment: I tried this, and after that I restarted the docker service. Still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: /etc/default/docker is a vendor specific file (RHEL/CentOS) and won't work in all environments or with Docker installed directly from the Docker repos.